# Regular expressions (grep) to match a repetitive two-letter pattern

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want to use a regular expression that would match the pattern 'ATATAT' (of any length) and/or 'GCCGCCGCC' (again of any length) in a text file. I have only four options and one of them should work, but I have tried all of them on a text file containing those patterns several times. But any of the codes below either don't return anything or end up in an error: "grep: Invalid back reference". Maybe I shouldn't be using grep at all?

- [ATGC]{2,}
- ([ATGC]{2,})\1+
- ([ATGC]{2,}){2,}
- ([ATGC])\1+

Principally, the code I am using is the following:

```
grep 'one_of_the_patterns_above' DNA_sequence_file.fasta
```

And the file looks something like this:

```
>sampled sequence 1 consisting of 500 bases.
GCAAAGTAGCCGAGGTCAGGGCATGTCAATGATAGCGCGAAAAGGTCACCACGAGAAGCG
GCACTCGGCCACGGATTGGTGGCACTTCATATGGAAACGCGACGACCGATAAAAACACAA
CGAAACCCAATTGGAATGAGATTTTCCTGAAACCGCAGCGAACCCAACCAAGCGGGAATA
AAGTCGGGAAGTCTAAACGAGATTAGCAGAATCCACCTCAGAATGACTGATGCCATGTAG
GCGCAGCAATAGATTACCGAAAGAGAAACACAGCAACGGATACATACAACTCAAGGGAAG
AGCACCTTTCGCTGAGAGGAGACGCCTTACAAACTATCCAGGGGTTTGAACAAGACAGGT
CGAAAAGCGGCCCTCTTCACAACCAGGTCAAGCGCGACTCGAGACAAGTATTCCCAAAGT
CCAAAAAAGAATCCTACAGAATCCCATCAAAGCATTTGTAGAAAGACATGGCCTACCAGC
TGCGCAAAGGACACATTACC
```

Comment: Are you playing with dns sequences? :-) Wow! :-)

Comment: @peterh Yes, exactly! Sorry, I actually forgot to post my code and a small file sample.. I will do that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to match "AT" repeated at least twice, or, in your other example, "GCC" repeated at least twice. Those would be, respectively:

```
(AT){2,}
(GCC){2,}
```

Note that you will have to use `grep -E` for these patterns to match. (There isn't a single, consistent syntax for regular expressions that works identically across tools, so you may have to adapt depending on which you end up using.)

Comment: Wow, this seems to be exactly what I forgot to have in my code; the extended expression.. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score -1):

All of the patterns are bad, they match any ATGC in any order. The correct regexp is:

```
^((AT)*|(GCC)*)$
```

This is doing what you wrote.